# centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI: only called once per advertising period

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to capture all BLE device advertisements.
The BLE device is set to wake ever minute then broad cast every 3 seconds for a total of 15 seconds.

But I have noticed centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI: is only called once per advertising period (15 seconds) that is seen by the handset while the app is in the foreground.

This is what I have monitored over the last couple of hours. Which has generate two questions.

One, How can i capture ever 3 second advertisement for the 15 second period?
Two, Why are there increasing dead periods in my captured data.

[image]

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 0):

[CentralManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager) has an option *CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey* wehn you initiate Scanning
by default it is false.

Set it to true and you should get multiple scans for the same device

```
scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true])
```